# How to access post data in php objects and functions?

Tags: php, post, request

Am finding it difficult to access post data across my php objects and functions.

Am using Xampp server on windows

```
$firstName =  isset($_POST['firstname']) ? $_POST['firstname'] : NULL;
```

I expect that on sending a post request to the page the variable `$firstName` will contain the post data `$_POST['firstname']`. However, `$firstName` is null but if i use `$_POST['firstname']` i will see the result.

I also need to access `$firstName` across multiple functions and objects.

Comment: Can you post the HTML form you are using?

Comment: Welcome to SO. There is nothing in what you've posted to account for the reported behaviour. We would need to see more code.

Comment: If $_POST['firstname'] gives you your result, why bother with using the isset enclosure?

Comment: You can show form code and output `var_damp($_POST)` or `print_r($_POST)` and check maybe you modified $_POST yearly.

Comment: Thanks the html file is submitting to the page with the code but it seems that i can not duplicate it into another variable.

Comment: i can not also access a variable across different functions e.g $var = "hello world"; function hello() { echo $var; } wont work

Comment: @iamoracle that's a scope issue.  You can always pass variables to your functions (this way at least is explicit).  http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php